# Tell someone that something vs. Tell someone about something vs. Tell someone something

Tags: sentence-construction

I wrote a sentence as below. A friend of mine posted his difficulty of waking up in the morning so I want to advise him to use snoring prevention product. Following sentence was the first line that I wrote.

I would like to know you can understand the meaning of my sentence.

> "Someone told me that his hard morning like you."

Comment: Well, the first part is correct while the second part isn't. Did you want to say that the "morning" of that someone is as hard as that of "you"? Then simply say, "Someone told me his morning was as hard as yours". Still "hard" sounds awkward to me, since it can mean whatever it wants.

Comment: why would a snoring prevention product help someone with waking up in the morning?

Comment: @AlanSutherland if someone feels tired when they wake up. Sleep apnea could be a reason of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone told me that his hard morning like you.

It is difficult for me to understand this.  Do you mean the following things?

- Someone told me something.
- He told me that his mornings are hard (meaning, that it is hard for him to wake up).
- He is like you because your mornings are also hard.

If that is your meaning, I would phrase it one of these ways:

- **"Someone told me that he has hard mornings like you."**
- **"Someone told me that his mornings are hard like yours."**

Are the differences clear?  The problem in the original sentence is that "his hard morning like you" does not have a verb, but a verb is expected to follow the word *that* in the phrase "Someone told me that...".

If you would also like advice on the phrasing of your question, I'll address that, too.  It was pretty good and merely needs adjustments.

> I wrote a sentense as below. A friend of mine posted his difficulty of waking up in the morning so I want to advise him to use snoring prevention product. Following sentence was the first line that I wrote.
>
> I would like to know you can understand the meaning of my intense.

You might write this instead (*italics* indicate changes):

**"I wrote *the sentence below*.  A friend of mine posted *about* his difficulty *with* waking up in the *morning, so* I want to advise him to use a snoring prevention product.  *The* following sentence was the first line that I wrote.**

In the last sentence, *intense* is not a noun, so I have to guess.  It's either:

**I would like to know *if* you can understand the meaning of my sentence.**

or

**I would like to know *if* you can understand my intent.**

I hope this is helpful.  Keep up the good work!